# Web application deployed through NetBeans but can't be accessed

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I have NetBeans 8.0.2 and GlassFish 4.1. I did an application in NetBeans 7 and GlassFish 3.

When I deploy my application. I don't have any error and I can see my application deployed in the admin console but when I tried to access to my application in the browser, I have a message that show:

> The requested resource is not available.

What can I do?

Thank you

**EDIT 1**

I'm working in OSx now... But I put the exactly same configuration in my virtual machine with Window 8 and it's WORK !!!! I also try to take the WAR created in the Window to put in the glassfish in OSx and also WORK !!! So I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with my code or with glassfish !!! It could be Netbeans (but I tried to reinstall it 3 times !!) Or some rules in OSx ? Do you have any idea ??? what It could be ?

**Edit 2**

I know that my JAR doesn't content the package org.netbeans.rest.application.config and this is the problem.... Someone know how to fix that ?

thank you

Comment: The message implication : you are probably trying to access a resource (a web page) which does not exist in the deployed WAR or you might have provided a wrong URL. Please try scanning the file system to see, if the web resource you are trying to access is actually available in the deployed WAR (the message says that it is unavailable there). NetBeans on the other hand, should have got nothing to do with it.

Comment: I don't get it: "*I have NetBeans 8.0.2 and GlassFish 4.1*" vs. "* did an application in NetBeans 7 and GlassFish 3*" what exactly *are* you using?

Comment: It could mean that the application was previously using this environment : NetBeans 7 and GlassFish 3 but it was upgraded afterwards to use this environment : NetBeans 8.0.2 and GlassFish 4.1. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Exactly that Tiny :D sorry for the misunderstanding... :D

But I'm sur about the URL.. I'm calling a Webservice with this URL : https://127.0.0.1:8181/Plugin/resources/pays... Normally the server give me an XML and now I have this error... And I'm sure this is working beacause the server ask me about the basic authentification....

Comment: And in the app deployed in the admin of Glassfish, I can see that all of my RETFull service are correctly deployed....

Comment: Finally, I have a new folder in my Netbean when I build my app : Generated Sources. I never seen this folder before my problem come... And inside this folder, I only have my entity and not my Service or JPA...

Comment: That "*Generated Sources*" thing is just an auto-generated stub having stub classes and should be looking something like this `Generated Sources (ap-source-output)` which is generated by the JPA Metamodel Generator containing static metamodel classes of JPA entity classes whose names basically end with an underscore `_`. If you have JAX-WS services, the stub should be looking something like `Generated Sources (jax-ws)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I have "Generated Sources (ap-source-output)" But I never seen that before... But I have JAX-WS Services (import javax.ws.rs.*;) in all of my service.. but never seen the second thing you told me....